# Can you use mat-progress-bar inside another mat-progress-bar in angular material?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

So I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to "inset" two mat-progress-bar spinners inside one another in Angular-material.
[Example picture of the implementation I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty6pc.png). So far I haven't come up with a solution exept to maybe just try to move one of the spinners inside the other and scale it down somehow.. could that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set them both in a div and use absolute position

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-corfs4?file=src/app/progress-spinner-overview-example.html